# Iterate individual elements in python sets

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, iteration, hashtable

Given m **sets** of integers that have n elements.

I have the below code, which outputs the element which occurs maximum number of times.

```
def find_element_which_appeared_in_max_sets(input_set):

    hash_table = {}

    # count the frequencies
    for pair in input_set:
        for i in range(0,len(pair)):
            if pair[i] in hash_table:
                hash_table[pair[i]] = hash_table[pair[i]] + 1
            else:
                hash_table[pair[i]] = 1 # first occurence

    # scan and find the element with highest frequency.
    max_freq = 0
    for elem in hash_table:

        if hash_table[elem] > max_freq:
            max_freq = hash_table[elem]
            max_occured_elem = elem

    return max_occured_elem


input_set = {(5,4),(3,2),(4,3),(8,3)}
print ""+str(find_element_which_appeared_in_max_sets(input_set))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Is there a **more neater/elegant way** of iterating through individual elements of the set?

Comment: Do you mean a `set` of `m` `tuples` that have `n` elements?

Comment: for starters, `for i in range(0,len(pair)):` should just be `for i in pair:`

Comment: Yes,  say m = 4 and n = 2  then input is input_set = {(5,4),(3,2),(4,3),(8,3)}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), like this

```
def find_element_which_appeared_in_max_sets(input_set):
    return Counter(chain.from_iterable(input_set)).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

`chain.from_iterable(input_set)` will flatten out the input set of tuples to get a single iterable which gives values from each of the tuples, one by one.

Then `Counter` counts the number of times each and every item occurred and  maintains the item and its count as a dictionary.

Then the `most_common(1)` call on `Counter` returns a list of items with top `n` (parameter passed to it) maximum number of occurrences, in the format `(item, count)`. Since we are only interested in the item, we return the first item with `[0][0]`.

Answer (score 4):

Using only built-ins, without standard library imports:

```
def find_element_which_appeared_in_max_sets(input_set):
    hash_table = {}
    for pair in input_set:
        for item in pair:
            #enhanced as proposed by thefourtheye
            hash_table[item] = hash_table.get(item, 0) + 1
    max_occured_element = max(hash_table, key=hash_table.get)
    return max_occured_element
```

Comment: Your `if..else` can be replaced with this `hash_table[item] = hash_table.get(item, 0) + 1`

Comment: @thefourtheye can you explain hash_table.get(item, 0)